# Agora.io message spamming: SO register failed, so could not monitor it

Tags: ios, agora.io

Can somebody please tell me why this log message spams when I start my app?

I have tried running my project on an iOS 15 simulator, and on real devices using iOS 16.6 and 17.3. My project contains no Agora.io code, but it includes the package dependency for AgoraRTCKit 4.3.0. This message does not appear when I run a simple project without an AgoraRTCKit package dependency.

The exact messages:

```
SO register failed, so could not monitor it.
SO register failed, so could not monitor it.
SO register failed, so could not monitor it.
SO register failed, so could not monitor it.
SO register failed, so could not monitor it.
SO register failed, so could not monitor it.
SO register failed, so could not monitor it.
SO register failed, so could not monitor it.
SO register failed, so could not monitor it.
SO register failed, so could not monitor it.
SO register failed, so could not monitor it.
SO register failed, so could not monitor it.
```